# Azure Cosmos DB Mongo API Bulk Operations using BulkExecutor .Net SDK - MongoBulkExecutor

Tags: azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

MongoBulkExecutor provided in Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.BulkExecutor
has two overloads:
a)public MongoBulkExecutor(DocumentClient client, DocumentCollection documentCollection); shows deprecated
b)public MongoBulkExecutor(Uri serviceEndpoint, string masterKey, string databaseName, string collectionName, ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy = null, ConsistencyLevel? desiredConsistencyLevel = null, JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings = null);

Question:
a) The second overload also expects a Uri ServiceEndpoint. In the overview page we can see a URI. - Is that the value?
b) Master Key is asked as the second value, which is not found anywhere in the portal - Could you advise what should be taken.

I tried giving the uri from the portal , and masterkey as the username and the application breaks

with the following error

Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient..ctor(System.Uri, System.String, System.EventHandler`1<Microsoft.Azure.Documents.SendingRequestEventArgs>, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ConnectionPolicy, System.Nullable`1<Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ConsistencyLevel>, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ApiType, System.EventHandler`1<Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ReceivedResponseEventArgs>, System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.ISessionContainer, System.Nullable`1, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.IStoreClientFactory)'.

Could you provide some documentation on how the MongoBulkExceutor could be made in use.
Or is it still version which cannot be used.

Comment: This library has been retired and should not be used. If you need to load data into the Cosmos DB MongoDB API refer to the migration guidance found here, https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-pre-migration

Comment: thankyou for the quick response @MarkBrown.
Can we use the BulkExecutor .net Library for the Cosmos DB SQL API Bulk Execution? Or is it recommended that we move to the .Net SDK V3. 

One more challenge we faced when using BulkExecutor .net library was:
We migrated data from JSON files to Cosmos DB SQL Account 
SourceJsonFiles = 1GB Data
When they reached Cosmos DB SQL Account it became 6GB of data.
Is this expected?

Comment: You cannot use any Cosmos DB SDK for MongoDB API. They can only be used with Cosmos DB Core (SQL) API. If you are using the Core API, yes you should use .NET SDK v3 rather than the bulk executor library. This library is built on .NET SDK v2 and will be deprecated shortly. The bloat can be caused by how many indexes you have. Is this for MongoDB API or SQL API? The MongoDB API 3.2 and 3.6 had issues with bloat. The newer 4.0 server version has much better storage.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.

The bloat is happening for the Cosmos SQL API. 
We are using the Bulk Exceutor .Net Library(Will Change it as you suggested). 
We have used 
IndexingMode = None, Partition Key = 1 and no composite indexes
Table Record Count = 6666666
Source Size in MB = 1002
When migrated using Bulk Executor to Cosmos SQL API The size = 7.72 GB
@MarkBrown